# Is there a way i could make this chessAI run faster?

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence, chess, minimax

I recently have been working on a chessAI in c++.
I have been able to implement the minimax algorithm, although i do find it very slow because the time it takes the computer to generate a move with a 3-ply depth is about 5-10 seconds and more than 30 seconds for a 4-ply deep search.

Is there any way i could make the following code faster?

Utils.h:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#define isinbtw(x, l1, l2) x > l2 && x < l1

typedef std::pair<short, short> Tile;

std::string vectp(std::vector<Tile> vec); // vector print, returns a string that can be printed that visualizes the contents of the vector | <Tile> type

bool invect(std::vector<Tile> haystack, Tile needle);

std::string pairp(Tile t);
```

Random utilities and debugging functions.

Evaluate.cpp:

```cpp
#include "Evaluate.h"



std::pair<Tile, Tile> findBestMove(Chess::Board& board, short color) {

    std::pair<Tile, Tile> bestMove;
    float bestMoveScore = INFINITY;

    for (Tile t : board.getTiles()) {
        if (board.getPiece(t).color == color) {
            for (Tile move : Chess::generateLegalMoves(board, t)) {
                board.movePiece(t, move);
                
                float score = moveScore(board, 0, color);

                board.movePiece(move, t);

                if (score < bestMoveScore) {
                    bestMove.first = t; 
                    bestMove.second = move;
                    bestMoveScore = score;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return bestMove;  
}

float moveScore(Chess::Board board, short depth, short color) {
    if (depth == (short) 3) {
        return Evaluate(board);
    }

    depth += 1;
    if (!color) {
        float maxEval = -INFINITY;
        for (Tile t : board.getTiles()) {
            if (board.getPiece(t).color == color) {
                for (Tile move : Chess::generateLegalMoves(board, t)) {
                    board.movePiece(t, move);
                    float eval = moveScore(board, depth, !color);
                    board.movePiece(move, t);

                    if (eval > maxEval) {
                        maxEval = eval;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return maxEval;
        
    }
    else {
        float minEval = INFINITY;
        for (Tile t : board.getTiles()) {
            if (board.getPiece(t).color == color) {
                for (Tile move : Chess::generateLegalMoves(board, t)) {
                    board.movePiece(t, move);
                    float eval = moveScore(board, depth, !color);
                    board.movePiece(move, t);

                    if (eval < minEval) {
                        minEval = eval;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return minEval;
    }

}


float Evaluate(Chess::Board evaluateBoard) {
    static int evaluateCalls = 0;
    float blackScore;
    float whiteScore;
    for (Tile t : evaluateBoard.getTiles()) {
        Chess::Piece currentPiece = evaluateBoard.getPiece(t);
        if (currentPiece.type == KING) {
            currentPiece.color == WHITE ? whiteScore += 900 : blackScore += 900;
        }
        if (currentPiece.type == QUEEN) {
            currentPiece.color == WHITE ? whiteScore += 90 : blackScore += 90;
        }
        if (currentPiece.type == BISHOP) {
            currentPiece.color == WHITE ? whiteScore += 30 : blackScore += 30;
        }
        if (currentPiece.type == KNIGHT) {
            currentPiece.color == WHITE ? whiteScore += 30 : blackScore += 30;
        }
        if (currentPiece.type == ROOK) {
            currentPiece.color == WHITE ? whiteScore += 50 : blackScore += 50;
        }
        if (currentPiece.type == PAWN) {
            currentPiece.color == WHITE ? whiteScore += 10 : blackScore += 10;
        }
    }

    evaluateCalls += 1;
    //std::cout << evaluateCalls << std::endl;
    return whiteScore - blackScore;
}
```

This is the code responsable for looking through the minimax tree and then choosing accordingly.

Chess.h:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

#include "Utils.h"

#define KING 0
#define QUEEN 1
#define BISHOP 2
#define KNIGHT 3
#define ROOK 4
#define PAWN 5

#define WHITE 0
#define BLACK 1

namespace Chess {

    class Piece {

        public:
            short color;
            short type;
            std::string uniqueCode;

            Piece();

            Piece(char fenChr);

            Piece(short pType, short pColor);

    };

    class Board {
        private:
            std::map<Tile, Piece> _board;
            std::vector<Tile> enpassant;
            bool whiteKingsidecastle = false;
            bool whiteQueensidecastle = false;
            bool blackKingsidecastle = false;
            bool blackQueensidecastle = false;
            short currentPlayer = 0;
            

        public:
            Board(std::string fenStr); // Construct a board object given a fen board

            bool inBoard(Tile t); // Check if there is a piece at a given position (t)

            std::vector<Tile> getPiecesPositions(); // Get all the pieces positions

            bool inEnpassant(Tile t); // Check if a piece at a given position (t) is eligible for enpassant (it's first move and it has moved by two tiles)

            Piece getPiece(Tile t); // Get the piece that is at a given position (t)

            void movePiece(Tile pos1, Tile pos2); // Move a piece at a give position (pos1) to a new position (pos2)

            std::string toFen(); // Return the fen equivalent of the current board

            short getCurrentPlayer(); // Get the color of whoever has the right to move

        
    };


    // Chess engine functions migrated from python to C++
    
    std::vector<Tile> generateLegalMoves(Board& board, Tile pos); // Choose based on the type of the piece at a given position (pos) which one of the move-generating functions to call

    bool checkIfInAllLegalMoves(Board& board, Tile move, short color); // Check if a given position (or move) is in the array of possible moves that a side/player can make

    std::vector<Tile> findBeam(Board& board, Tile pos);

    std::vector<Tile> pawnMoves(Board& board, Tile pos);

    std::vector<Tile> rookMoves(Board& board, Tile pos);

    std::vector<Tile> bishopMoves(Board& board, Tile pos);

    std::vector<Tile> knightMoves(Board& board, Tile pos);

    std::vector<Tile> queenMoves(Board& board, Tile pos);

    std::vector<Tile> kingMoves(Board& board, Tile pos);
}
```

This is how i have approached the representation of the board.

Comment: If you want help improving working code, you should post this on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  If you do decide to do so, please delete the question here.

Comment: Also, when you timed this, did you compile with optimizations turned on?

Comment: What did you see when you profiled your code?  It looks like you have a lot of unnecessary copies via function parameters

Comment: Recently I've been introduced to coz-profiler. Might give you better hints what to optimize than traditional profilers.

Comment: Please edit your post with the definition of `class Tile`.

Comment: Its in the first file, Tile is just a typedef of a std::pair<short, short>

Comment: If you're doing minimax without any pruning, you should get a branching factor of approximately 20~25 (in opening game), which is not consistent with the observed timings. My first recommendation would be to count the number of nodes in your search tree and compare them with [those of perft](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Perft_Results).